# IOS Release Build Failed: Could not find the expected embedded asset at-rules.json. Check that expo-updates is installed correctly

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, expo

My React Native app works fine in iOS debug mode. But, when I tried to run the app in release mode from xCode, the build is failed. However, in android, it works fine in both debug and release mode.

```
File /Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-ewjafyqwkgvybabvuzpfqtubujvv/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/ios.app/main.jsbundle does not exist. This must be a bug with.
```

Then I tried generating the `main.jsbundle` manually by running the following command and adding this `main.jsbundle` in `Copy Bundle Resources` in `Build Phases` from XCode.

```
npx react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios
```

Still, I am not being able to build the ios app in release mode but this time the build succeed but the app doesn't show anything in screen and the error i got in Xcode is:

```
Could not find the expected embedded asset at-rules.json. Check that expo-updates is installed correctly.
```

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I'm still struggling with that.

Comment: @ThomasDittmar Yes, but I did it by creating a new react-native-cli project and migrating all the js/ts files as well as assets to the new project. Also, use alternative packages for expo related dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The project I’m working on is legacy code. I would never touch that Expo shit. Im going to convert it into a bare RN too.